# PhoneStateListener is never called in broadcast android

Tags: android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

my broadcast is getting called but PhoneStateListener is not called my code works fine when I run it in emulator but when I try it on actual device PhoneStateListener never gets a call, I am going nutts on this problem 
Here is my code:

```
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); //TelephonyManager object  
                            CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();  
                            telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); //Register our listener with TelephonyManager
```

the above code is in onReceive() method and here is my class extensing  PhoneStateListener
outside onReceive() but in broadcast class.

```
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {  

        private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";  



        @Override  
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phonenumber){  

            if(phonenumber!=null && phonenumber.length()>0) 
                incoming_nr=phonenumber;   
            act=new Call_RecorderActivity();

            switch(state){  
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:  
                        Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_RINGING");  
                        prev_state=state;  


                        break;  


                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  
                Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");  
                prev_state=state;  

                break;  


                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:  
                     prev_state=state;
                     Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDLE==>"+incoming_nr);



                    break;  
                   // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
                   // |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

            } //switch close
        }
}
```

logcat shows this on incoming call

```
01-22 11:25:12.529: I/IncomingCallReceiver(1463): Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=168]
01-22 11:25:12.539: I/IncomingCallReceiver(1463): State: RINGING
01-22 11:25:12.539: I/IncomingCallReceiver(1463): Incomng Number: +9184848xxxx2
01-22 11:25:12.779: D/CustomPhoneStateListener(1463): CALL_STATE_IDLE==>+9184848xxxx2
01-22 11:25:16.299: I/IncomingCallReceiver(1463): Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=92]
01-22 11:25:16.299: I/IncomingCallReceiver(1463): State: OFFHOOK
01-22 11:25:18.849: I/IncomingCallReceiver(1463): Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=88]
01-22 11:25:18.849: I/IncomingCallReceiver(1463): State: IDLE
```

Any suggestion related to it will be accepted
Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure you have added `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE ` permission in Manifest

Comment: yes i have added that permission

Comment: show us your logs and cats

Comment: are you publishing your receiver in the manifest, or are you registering it at runtime with `registerReceiver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service is getting cleaned up before the callback gets invoked.  You should not really be relying on anything allocated in your `BroadcastReceiver` to exist after `onReceive` exits.  You should put `CustomPhoneStateListener` in `Service` or `Activity`.  Then you can use an `Intent` to launch the activity or service to do your state monitoring.

From the `BroadcastReceiver` docs,

> Once you return from onReceive(), the BroadcastReceiver is no longer
>   active, and its hosting process is only as important as any other
>   application components that are running in it. This is especially
>   important because if that process was only hosting the
>   BroadcastReceiver (a common case for applications that the user has
>   never or not recently interacted with), then upon returning from
>   onReceive() the system will consider its process to be empty and
>   aggressively kill it so that resources are available for other more
>   important processes.

The reason it is working on the emulator is probably because there are less processes in general on the emulator and for some reason it seems less aggressive about killing off processes.

Comment: @Auto-Droid The reason it is working on the emulator is probably because there are less processes in general on the emulator and for some reason it seems less aggressive about killing off processes.  Therefore, your process is still in memory in the emulator, but not on the device.  It does not change the fact that, per the documentation, you have no assurance that the process will be spared.  As such, your code as written above as may or may not work on any given invocation.

Comment: I took service which would detect Phone state for me but my service gets called but still the problem of my listener not getting a call remains

Comment: What broadcast intent are you listening for to launch your service?  I was able to copy your code into the `onStartCommand` of a `Service` and it logged all the states messages fine on a real device.

Comment: context.startService(new Intent(context,MyService.class));

Comment: @Auto-Droid I meant what triggers your broadcast receiver?

Comment: I use this code to start the service and Registered my listener in onStart command and copyed my listener class inside my service

Comment: I have registered my receiver class in manifest which get called during incomming call by using android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23186/discussion-between-iagreen-and-auto-droid)

Comment: pls tell me how did you got success in getting phone state

Answer (score 0):

Tthe solution for above problem is:

```
private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {  

    @Override 

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {  

        String callState = "UNKNOWN";  

        String myNumber = tm.getLine1Number();
        switch (state) {  

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:  

            callState = "IDLE";
            if(Status!=""){
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Call Ends " + incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;  

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: 
            Status = "RINGING";
            if (incomingNumber.startsWith("00")) {  
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"International Call- " + incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                callState = "International - Ringing (" + incomingNumber+ ")";  
            } else {  
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Local Call - " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                callState = "Local - Ringing (" + incomingNumber + ")";  
            }  
            break;  
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  

            try{
                String dialingNumber = mIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);  
                if(dialingNumber==null){
                    Status = "Recieve";
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Recieve call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Status = "Dialing";
                    if (dialingNumber.startsWith("00")) {  
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"International - " + dialingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                        callState = "International - Dialing (" + dialingNumber+ ")";  
                    } else {  
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Local Call - " + dialingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                        callState = "Local - Dialing (" + dialingNumber + ")";  
                    }  
                }
            }catch(Exception e){}

            break;  

        }  

        Log.i(">>>Broadcast", "onCallStateChanged " + callState);  

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);  

    }  

};
```